# Latitude E6400 Screen is Black

Tags: windows-7, boot, display, graphics-card, dell-latitude

The screen to my Latitude E6400 is all black, I have been able to see the screen, but dark on other computers, I can see everything fine, but it is just really dark.  If I put a flashlight right up next to the screen, I can see it.

Is the back-light broken? or is thit just off? I have tried turning it on, but it might be shut off.

It seems like I had the same problem with a Dell Inspiron 1500

Comment: If you connect it to a monitor, does the monitor show anything?

Comment: [Service Manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e6400_service%20manual_en-us.pdf)

Comment: The "graphics card" isn't a separate part on most laptops; it's normally soldered onto the motherboard (there are exceptions, but according to the manual this isn't one of them). That means that it's incredibly unlikely that it came unattached (it could be broken, but it's probably still attached).

Comment: Last time it happened it worked, I havn't tried on this one yet.

Comment: @JustWondering With the edit: Can you see things when shining a strong flashlight at the screen, or is it blank even then?

Comment: I can see it fine with a flashlight, yes. The colors are fine too. I am currently attached to a second monitor and the monitor is displaying things fine.